# Trying to parse a json crashes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I have got the following json

```
 {"status":1,"value":{"details":{"40404000024769":[{"name":"","email":""}]}}}
```

Im parsing it as follows,

```
NSString *statusCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonDic[@"status"]];
             NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];
             NSArray *details = [valueDict objectForKey:@"details"];

             NSLog(@"%@",details);
             for (NSDictionary *response in details){
                 NSLog(@"adsf %@",response);
             }
         }
```

Following is my error log

This can get the only `40404000024769` but not the value of `40404000024769`. 
I tried using`[response valueForKey:@"name"]` and the app crashes. 
How can I be able to get the value of name, email?

```
2016-04-27 16:24:02.967 Vaighai Export[311:10625] ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:'[<__NSCFString 0x14e56870> valueForUndefinedKey:]:this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

Comment: can u show the crash report

Comment: Details has a dictionary as value. Not an array

Comment: @user31231234124 any reason why you removed accepted answer from me and gave it to abhinandan who basically who basically copied code from my answer and did not even bother to change variable names? Is he your proxy account?

Comment: I hope you are not serial upvoting me now? It's unnecessary. The voting will be reversed in 24 hours and It won't have any effects on me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON structure is:

```
-NSDictionary
--Number
--NSDictionary
---NSDictionary
----NSDictionary
-----NSArray
------NSDictionary
```

The key `details` has a dictionary against it as value, not an array as you have assumed. Change your code to this:

**NOTE:** This is only sample to show you how you were parsing it wrong. You need to handle cases for your real world json in your app.

```
NSString *statusCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",jsonDic[@"status"]]; //We got status
NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"]; //We got value dic
NSDictionary *detailDic = [valueDict objectForKey:@"details"]; //We got details dic

NSArray * internalArr = [detailDic objectForKey:@"40404000024769"]; //We got array of dictionaries
 //Iterate over this array to log internal dictionaries
for(NSDictionary *nameDic in internalArr)
{
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ email: %@",[nameDic objectForKey:@"name"],[nameDic objectForKey:@"email"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly from the details dictionary fetch allkeys after that put that keys in the array then at zero index of that array the key is available find the array inside that key.

Comment: can you please elaborate it with reference to my code?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];

    NSDictionary *details = [valueDict objectForKey:@"details"];

    NSArray *YourArray= [details  objectForKey:@"40404000024769"];

    NSString *Name = [YourArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *Email = [YourArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"email"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`status` is an integer

```
NSInteger statusCode = [jsonDic[@"status"] integerValue];
```

`value` contains a dictionary `details`

```
NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];
NSDictionary *details = [valueDict objectForKey:@"details"];
```

`details` contains an array in a dictionary. In item 0 of the array there is a dictionary containing the requested `name` and `email` keys.

```
for (NSString *key in details){
   NSLog(@"key %@",key);
   NSDictionary *data = details[key][0];
   NSLog(@"name %@ - email %@", data[@"name"], data[@"email"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

key `details` is a dictionary not an array.

Just add one line in to fetch `40404000024769` key value.

Change your code as bellow:

```
NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];
NSDictionary *details = [valueDict objectForKey:@"details"];
NSArray *ar = [details objectForKey:@"40404000024769"];
for (NSDictionary *response in ar){
    NSLog(@"name: %@ email: %@",[response objectForKey:@"name"],[response objectForKey:@"email"]);
}
```